# Would it be better to do a sepparate query instead of a left JOIN?

Tags: mysql, join

Only a couple of rows is returned when not using `LEFT` since there isn't always data in the associated table - `recipe_preparation`. This is one of a couple of tables with the same "issue".

```
SELECT r.id, r.name,
    rp.explanation preparation,
    g.name
FROM recipes r
    LEFT JOIN recipes_preparation rp ON r.id = rp.fk_recipes_id AND rp.in_use = 1
    JOIN glassware g ON r.fk_glassware_id = g.id
```

*The reason to why the preparation details is in a sepparate table is because of the ability to suggest/submit a better explanation. This is so the user can add their own/select a preffered one, and connect it to their account..

The `AND rp.in_use` is for the public one.*

Anyway; I've read somewhere that using `LEFT` is more expensive, and that it should be avoided if possible. I could query `recipes` and only `JOIN` `glasses`. Then, in my application, I could just do a new query on each recipes to check if there's any data to retrieve.

What would be the better solution?
and as I mentioned before; this is just one of several other tables with this "issue"..

UPDATE:
Here is a EER diagram that I'm working with:

[image: EER Diagram]

I've added a couple of more tables after this screenshoot was taken, and the `in_use` column in `recipes_preparation` (not indexed)..
Maybe this could tell a little more...

UPDATE #2:
I looked into the `EXPLAIN` statment, and this is the result I got - which didn't tell me much at first.
[image: Result of using EXPLAIN statement]

Looks like it starts with table `g`(glasses)? And it looks like it uses `ALL` as the join type - which is not good since that is a full table scan according to the MySQL Refrence..
Also; "MySQL found no index to use for executing the query more efficiently" more than? - the `PK`? - or non at all?

Comment: Try it and see.  Less glib, what does the query plan look like?  Honestly if you're querying recipes, you probably don't have enough records for it to matter much.  You can often get to millions of records before you need to start second-guessing the optimizer.

Comment: what do you mean by "less glib"? What is "glib"? Is there a way to test different queries in mysql workbench to see which execute faster or better?

Comment: My comment to "try it and see" was glib, meaning more clever than helpful.  I'm making the point that you can simply run the query, change it, and run it again.  Which one runs faster?  The less glib answer, meaning more helpful, is to analyze the query plan for your original query and see if it's efficient.

Comment: Looks like a good normalized database.  You should be fine.  `LEFT JOIN`s are not evil; I'd be more worried about table scans, and then only if a query actually does take a long time.

Comment: How do I analyze a query? Never done something like that before, but would be interresting to know. As I mentioned; I'm primarly working in MySQL Workbench..

Comment: I'm afraid that's a huge topic; there are shelves of books on the topic.  I would start here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/execution-plan-information.html.

Comment: Thanks Jon. But I have to ask, before I waste a whole lot of time with this one thing: No matter how I query - join tables together - I always get one record with `type`:`ALL`. Is this correct? Like the one in the image I've put in my question. The same happens when I try to query from the `_rel_`-tables, and joining the associated tables. The tags/raw_materials get `eq_ref` while the `recipes` is set to `ALL`. the `_rel_`-tables is set to `ref` and `extra`:`using index`. in both cases..

Comment: MySQL is doing a table scan of `glasses` because you're using the whole table: both `id` and `name`.  The alternative would be to seek the index a zillion times and do a row lookup for each, which won't be any faster in such a narrow table.  You'll get a table scan when the system thinks that will be faster than the alternatives.  Don't sweat it too much until and unless you get performance problems; just having a good normalized schema is the bigger part, and you have that.

Comment: Very well then. Knowing nothing was much better than knowing a litte. Everything was easier back then.. Anyway; Thanks for taking your time to reply. Helped a lot..

Comment: @ThomasK, allow me to suggest you ask a new Question, otherwise this is becoming a comment hell.

Comment: @ShlomiNoach, sorry about that..

Answer (score 1):

By your fine naming conventions I can take it that the `fk_recipes_id` column is indexed. This alone suggests that the query should be OK (pending cardinality of `fk_recipes_id`). If you further expand that index to include (`fk_recipes_id`, `in_use`), that would improve your query's execution plan.

Generally speaking, it is better to do a `JOIN` (including a `LEFT` one) within your database than to loop in your application code and submit multiple queries.

I can't know for sure what goes on in your app; you should indeed just test it as @Jon suggests. With a large dataset I suspect you will see the difference very quickly (and it will be in favour of the database `JOIN`).

Comment: I've added a EER diagram to my question.. Maybe it tells you a bit more...

Comment: How would I expand an index to cover both `fk_recipes_id` and `in_use`?

Comment: To "expand" an index just create a new one that includes both columns, and drop the original one.